# What part of the sentence is "you" in "telling you who that is"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

The object is "who that is", right?  And the verb is "telling", but what is "you"?

Further sentences:

- Did they give 'him' a reward?
- Will you be able to find 'them' a home?
- I have given 'her' a lot of money, and she has shown 'me' nothing in return.
- I want to buy ink from 'them'.  Not from '**them**'.
- My girlfriend gave 'me' a delicious bag of curry crackers, and I gave 'her' a delicious, curry-flavored kiss.
- His chariot sent 'him' airborne, and the tumble against the ground
  gave 'him' a cracked rib.

Comment: Can you give a full sentence? That would make things easier to parse.

Comment: Yeah, I guess.  No problem.

Comment: "Sent him airborne": *him* here is not an indirect object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

English is a language of verbs, so we first identify the verb to answer your question.

The verb is "telling."

With a transitive verb (as in this case), the direct object answers "what" or "whom." Now we ask, "Telling what?" The answer, "who that is," is the direct object.

The indirect object answers the question "to what" or "to whom." Now we ask, "Telling to whom?" The answer, "you," is the indirect object.

Putting this all together, we find that "telling" is the verb, "you" is the indirect object, and "who that is" is the direct object.

Comment: This seems to be a good answer from my follow-up research after having read it.  Thank you.